# Modify jquery code that gets .data into a javascript one

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using jquery right now to get the value for the id, like in the code bellow:

```
<ul class="trf noborder" data-id="6581">
</ul> 

var ID = $("ul.trf").data('id');
```

How can I do this using pure javascript? Do I need to add a span class or something?

Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it with pure javascript
depending on your needs and what kind of performance you expect. Here is one way using an ID:

```
<ul class="trf noborder" data-id="6581" id="myDiv">
</ul> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = document.getElementById("myDiv").getAttribute("data-id");
</script>
```

Or you can try this if you want to target a specific UL without any ID

```
<ul class="trf noborder" data-id="6581">
</ul> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getAttribute("data-id");
</script>
```

But you will have to make sure that you use the right index, here it will retrieve the first UL on your page. You could also wrap it in another container:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="trf noborder" data-id="6581"></ul> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var container = document.getElementById("container");
     var id = container.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getAttribute("data-id");
</script>
```

And it will use the first UL inside of that container. Or the third if you do it like this:

```
 var id = container.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].getAttribute("data-id");
```

It's based on the array index, 2 in this case (0, 1, 2 = third element)

If you don't want jQuery but still can be willing to use a library, look at http://sizzlejs.com which is a great selector engine (actually used by jQuery). With Sizzle you could do it like this:

```
var id = Sizzle("ul[data-id]")[0].getAttribute("data-id");
```

To get the data-id of the first UL on the page that has a data-id attribute specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use
`element.getAttribute('attribute_name')`
in pure JavaScript to get the value of any data attribute's value.

Example can be found here :
[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/dSzAJ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can read attribute with [getAttribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute) function. But you should gather element itself, calling getElementById or getElementsByTagname functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
getData: function(el, attr) {
  attr = 'data-' + attr;
  var result = (el.getAttribute && el.getAttribute(attr)) || null;

  if(!result) {
    var attrs = el.attributes;
    var length = attrs.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
      if(attrs[i].nodeName === attr)
        result = attrs[i].nodeValue;
  }

  return result;
}

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('trf')[0];
var id = getData(el, 'id');
```

Comment: Be aware that getElementsByClassName is not available in IE8 and below. There are some alternatives, for example http://www.webmuse.co.uk/blog/custom-getelementsbyclassname-function-for-all-browsers/ or the splendid SizzleJS http://sizzlejs.com (used by jQuery)

Comment: Can use `querySelector` to squeeze ie8 in

Comment: Well it doesn't work in IE7 but it works in IE8. Where as `.getElementsByClassName` only works in IE9. So you could do `var el = document.querySelector(".trf");` to get slightly more support :P

Comment: You can see in which browsers it's available on this page: http://caniuse.com/queryselector